# FluentIterable: How to keep the same input list order

Tags: java

```
Set<TypeOne> result = new LinkedHashSet<>(FluentIterable
                           .from(inputListTypeTwo)
                           .transform(new Function<TypeTwo, TypeOne>() {

            @Override
            public TypeOne apply(TypeTwo element) {
                return new TypeOne(element);
            }
      }).toList());
```

I get a different order in result !?

Guava 14.0.1 and Java 7

Comment: Do you? I just tried (http://paste.ofcode.org/jPi6aFE9JmPRbQyYpRTj9J) and the order is as expected (Java 8, Guava 20). Can you try to paste a runnable example? What version of Java and Guava are you using? Also, is there any specific reason for you not using the `toSet()` method on `FluentIterable`?

Comment: @Slanec does `toSet()` return a set with a specific iteration order?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Yes, it does. It returns an `ImmutableSet` and all Immutable structures in Guava retain their insertion order.
Also, I just tried with Java 7 and Guava 14. Still can't reproduce...

Comment: TL;DR: Use [`FluentIterable#toSet()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#toSet%28%29) without copying to `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: @Adil So, how did it go? Are you still seeing the effect? Did you sort this out in any way?

Comment: @Slanec: I have tested it with String/Integer as you have shown and it works fine, but when using my types and debuging I found a different order. Strange! Maybe I'm missing smthg

Comment: "*when using my types and debuging I found a different order*" - so please include your types and a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can replicate in your question. The issue is clearly with your type, not with `FluentIterable`.